# Fallout 3 GNR broadcasts file locations

Tags: fallout-3

So i was wondering; where are the files for the Galaxy News Radio broadcasts located? Im trying to put most of them together as one file, and maybe do some stuff with it or just upload it to some cloud. 
Thanks!

Comment: Going to upload copyrighted material? I'm afraid we cannot help you with that. Sorry.

Comment: He is able to provided that it is a personal cloud isn't he?